# Is there a way to see our own questions we've not checked as "accepted answer"?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, search, question-lists

I have asked a lot of questions on Stack Overflow and I would like to see which questions have got *at least* an answer but that I've not marked as "accepted answer".

I know I could watch under the `questions` tab and fetch all my questions but this may take a while (as I have asked 155 questions) till now.

Comment: Search using this: `user:me answers:1 hasaccepted:0`

Comment: May I ask you to answer the question? I would check it as valid.

Comment: Sure, will add an answer in a while. Btw, one minor correction I would like to mention here, the Stack Exchange community uses the term "accepted answer" instead of "valid". Thanks.

Comment: @AzizShaikh that correction can be a part of the answer, too ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Good suggestion, added that part in the answer as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using the following search term, you can view all of your questions which have got at least one answer but no answer has not been accepted yet.

> user:me answers:1 hasaccepted:0

By the way, one minor correction I would like to mention here, the Stack Exchange community uses the term "accepted answer" instead of "valid" (as you have used in your question).

The "green squares" on the search result page mean that the question has answer(s). In case of accepted answer, the count of answer(s) is filled with yellow color. In case of no accepted answer, is it in white (or no color). Screenshots given below:

A question with NO accepted answer:

[image: A question with no accepted answer]

A question with an accepted answer:

[image: A question with an accepted answer]

Comment: This doesnt work if I copy paste your code in the top right search box. Is it the right search box?

Comment: Ok, try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A106140+answers%3A1+hasaccepted%3A0). It is a URL of the same search page which will show your questions with atleast one answer but no accepted answer.

Comment: This brings me to the same "search results" page with "green squares" that show me all the questions, not only the ones that I've not marked as "accepted answer".

Comment: What is the total search results that you see? I see that you have 8 questions without an accepted answer and 142 questions with accepted answers. The "green squares" mean that the question has answer(s). In case of accepted answer, the number of answer(s) is filled with yellow. In case of no accepted answer is it white.

Comment: Your answer was prefect, my bad. Thank you very much indeed, have a great day!